# Onclick change 2 slideshow revolution JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, api

I need to `onclick change 2 slideshow`. I have used this code but work only `revapi2`.

My code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
//Revolution
  $('.tp-rightarrow').on('click', function() {
    revapi2.revnext();
    revapi3.revnext();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you show us a more complete code so we can understand ?

Comment: Hi, this is complete code. I use WordPress and Slideshow is in Revolution Slider. I need to change 2 different slide when I click on button next.